# Ionic 2 ionSwipe undefined error

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am trying to do a swipable list of items like this:

```
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let venue of venues" #slidingVenue>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-item-options side="right">
          <button ion-button color="primary" (click)="action(slidingVenue)">
            action1
          </button>
        </ion-item-options>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-item-sliding>
  </ion-list>
```

I receive the following error:

> item-sliding.js:160 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ionSwipe' of undefined

I tried to add `(ionSwipe)="someFunc()"` but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/item/ItemSliding/) your html code is wrong:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let venue of venues" #slidingVenue>

      <!-- Start ion-item -->
      <ion-item>
      </ion-item>
      <!-- End ion-item -->

      <!-- Start ion-item-options -->
      <ion-item-options side="right">
          <button ion-button color="primary" (click)="action(slidingVenue)">
            action1
          </button>          
      </ion-item-options>
      <!-- End ion-item-options -->

    </ion-item-sliding>
</ion-list>
```